# Finding the base address of a program via Visual Basic code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, memory, memory-address, base-address

I am using Visual Studio 2019 - Visual Basic.

I am trying to find the base address of a program via code. I know the base address already, but I need the program I am making to find it on its own.

I use this and it shows a lot of addresses from the modules:

```
Dim target As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("The Program")(0)
For Each mo As ProcessModule In target.Modules
    ListBox1.Items.Add(mo.BaseAddress.ToString())

    'MsgBox(Hex(mo.BaseAddress.ToString()))
Next
```

(I renamed the name of the program from the above code in case there are issues with the program as in copyright stuff.)

I am trying to get the base address
My base address I have is:

```
Base Address in Hex = 00007FF7BE6B0000
Base Address in Dec = 140702028333056
```

When I run the above code **none** of the addresses it lists are the base addresses I have.

I used a PE Editor to see the base address of the program. I used a program called [PE Tools](https://github.com/petoolse/petools/releases/tag/v1.9.762) from GitHub.

So how do I code to get this Image Base Address?

Comment: The base address is `target.MainModule.BaseAddress`, the Entry Point is `target.MainModule.EntryPointAddress` and the RVA is `p.MainModule.EntryPointAddress.ToInt64() - target.MainModule.BaseAddress.ToInt64()`

Comment: I have no idea what all that means... I apologize... I am still new to this...

Comment: Don't you have a Process object you got with `Dim target As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName("The Program)(0)`? Isn't this instance named `target`? (all right I wrote `p.MainModule.EntryPointAddress.ToInt64()` instead of `target. ...`, just a typo) Then...

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with this code:

```
Dim p As Process = Process.GetProcessesByName(GetCurrentProcessName)(0)
For Each moz As System.Diagnostics.ProcessModule In p.Modules
    If moz.FileName.IndexOf(GetCurrentProcessName) <> -1 Then
      Hex(moz.BaseAddress.ToString)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: please consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).